# Do equal topologies imply equivalent distance functions?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have been given the statement:

> Let $X$ be a set and $d, d'$ be distance functions on $X$. Then if $d$ and $d'$ are equivalent, their topologies $T$, $T'$ are equal.

To be clear, the definition I am familiar with for equivalent distances is that their convergent sequences are exactly equal and converge to the same points.

I am interested in proving the converse of this statement. That is, if $T$ and $T'$ are topologies of $X$ with respect to distance functions $d$ and $d'$, then $T=T'$ implies that $d$ and $d'$ are equivalent.

I have tried constructing an arbitrary convergent sequence in $(X, d)$ and showing that it is a convergent sequence in $(X, d')$, to no avail. I have also tried considering the fact that all open balls in $T$ are also in $T'$ and vice versa, but I'm not sure what to do with that information.

How would I go about proving this?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "equivalent". Will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{x_n\} \rightarrow x$ in the $T$ topology. Let $B'$ be a neighbourhood of $x$ in the $T'$ topology. Then, $B'$ is also a neighbourhood of $x$ in the $T$ topology (because they are equivalent). So, there is some $N$ such that for all $n \geq N, x_n \in B$, which implies that $\{x_n\} \rightarrow x$ in the $T'$ topology. Hence, any convergent sequence in $T$ converges to the same value in $T'$, and vice-versa.